# VBA Solver Not Resetting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues with my solver script not actually solving when I move between worksheets. The solver is supposed to maximize a reference cell up to 1 by changing 5 cells in a column 10 times per sheet.

```
wslist = Array("A", "B", "C")
For j = LBound(wslist) To UBound(wslist)
Worksheets(wslist(j)).Activate
For i = 0 To 9
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Precision:=0.1
    SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(7 + i * 4, 49), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(Cells(6, 18 + i), Cells(10, 18 + i)), _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Cells(7 + i * 4, 49), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
*Constraints Omitted*
    Next i
Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Solver does not seem to run when I move from worksheet A to B, i.e. the script runs fine on sheet A but when it's suppose to move to sheet B the script "runs" but solver does not change anything. If I go through and manually enter the exact same parameters into solver it does run.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Instead of calling SolverReset when you switch workpages, run Application.Run "SolverReset"